# Find sub-task with summary like 'QA' when every other sub-task is Done

Tags: jira, jql

I want to filter sub-tasks that have a summary like 'QA' only when any other sub-task has been completed.

That would give us QAs what's ready to be tested on a given sprint for example

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use issue types to represent the scope of the subtasks: Testing, Coding, etc. Then have a customfield (ReadyForQA) to be set to 1 in every sibling Testing subtask by a postfunction everytime you close the last sibling subtask whose type is other than Testing.
Jira Workflow Toolbox will help you to do this easily.

Comment: I guess the idea is not to use any add-on. There's functionality we should get without having to use the marketplace at all. 
The add-on you propose is for server only anyways but we're using cloud version

Comment: I don´t think you can achieve your goal as stated without any addon or programming (i.e. groovy). I also suggest to evaluate moving from cloud to server if you are looking using JIRA in ways that are not supported out of the box in Cloud.